# How to bring the image to the right of react Card

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react [Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJXv4.png).

I want to bring the image on the card to the right-side of card and it should also be parellel to the Name `Pankaj Rout`, and should be responsive.

This is what I have tried so far,

```js
var userMap = [
  {name: "Pankaj Rout", email: "pankaj.rout@somedomain.com"}
]

userData.map((data) => {
      return (
        <div key={data.email}>
          <Card style={cardStyle}>
            <Card.Body>
              <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                <img
                  className={classes.img}
                  style={cardImgStyle}
                  src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
                  alt="sans"
                />
              </div>
              <Card.Title> {data.name} </Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                General Manager
              </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Text> {data.email} </Card.Text>
                <Button> Delete </Button>
                <Button> Email </Button>
                <Button> Chat </Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
```

`classes` is used from `withStyles` hook

```js
const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  img: {
    justifyContent: 'right',
  }
});
```

following style is referring to `cardImgStyle`

```js
const cardImgStyle = {
  width: "30%",
  height: "30%",
  borderRadius: "50%",
  display: "flex",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
};
```

Could anyone please point out what is wrong here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Curious where did you find the ` align: 'right',` style ? :O . Anyway. Change the html structure. Have the `name` and the `img` in the same container ( in this order ) and use flexbox to align them

Comment: Hi @MihaiT, thanks for the quick response. Let me try this

Comment: Could you please write the working css for that division where both img and name would be present

Comment: well, please try first. Just change the HTML like i said in my previous comment. Then just check flexbox. ( i see you use flex in your code. ). Try it out. It won't hurt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

justifyContent : 'space-beetwin' ;

or

for img  :
float :' right';